# dynamic cast from a wrapper interface

Tags: c++, templates, casting

In C++, I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
struct IWrapper {
    template<typename U>
    U* dynamic_cast_to() { ??? } // what to do here?
};

template<typename T>
struct Wrapper : IWrapper {
    Wrapper(T* _p) :p(_p) {}    
    T* p;
};
```

With this I'd like to be able to do

```
SomeDerived *a = new SomeDerived;
IWrapper *x = new Wrapper<SomeDerived>(a);
SomeBase *b = x->dynamic_cast_to<SomeBase>()
```

`dynamic_cast_to()` should return a pointer if indeed `SomeDerived` inherits from `SomeBase` and `NULL` if not, the same way normal `dynamic_cast` works.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

give `IWrapper` a virtual destructor and use `dynamic_cast`.

i am amazed that the question is asked, how to implement a `dynamic_cast_to` function.

how can one *avoid* considering standard `dynamic_cast` then?

Comment: That would not work. Being able to `dynamic_cast` `SomeDerived` to `SomeBase` does not mean you can `dynamic_cast` `Wrapper<SomeDerived>` to `Wrapper<SomeBase>`. That's the whole point.

Comment: You asked to cast `Wrapper<SomeDerived>` to `SomeBase`, _not_ to `Wrapper<SomeBase>`. Which did you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done for arbitrary types T and U.  The reason is that
the compiler has to generate the dynamic_cast code for the specific pair of types at compile time, 
and there is no place where both types are known simultaneously at compile time.

If you could restrict IWrapper to just work for types derived from a certain base that had a virtual member function, then it could work like this:

```
struct IWrapper {
    template<typename U>
    U* dynamic_cast_to() { return dynamic_cast<U*>(commonBasePtr()); }

    virtual CommonBase* commonBasePtr() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Wrapper : IWrapper {
    Wrapper(T* _p) :p(_p) {}    
    T* p;

    virtual CommonBase* commonBasePtr() { return p; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible like that, because IWrapper doesn't know anything about T, nor has it access to the pointer. This should work:

```
template <typename T>
struct IWrapper {
    IWrapper(T* p) : p_(p) {}
    template<typename U>
    U* dynamic_cast_to() { return dynamic_cast<U*>(p_); }
private:
    T* p_;
};

template<typename T>
struct Wrapper : IWrapper<T> {
    Wrapper(T* _p) : IWrapper<T>(_p), p(_p) {}    
    T* p;
};

struct SomeBase {
    int a;
};

struct SomeDerived : public SomeBase {
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    SomeDerived *a = new SomeDerived;
    IWrapper<SomeDerived> *x = new Wrapper<SomeDerived>(a);
    SomeBase *b = x->dynamic_cast_to<SomeBase>();
    return b->a;
}
```